# Error on create trigger on PostreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I'm trying to import this trigger into a postgre database but i got an error.

This is my code

```
Select "comandes.before_insert_detall" AS "05";
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS before_insert_detall;
DELIMITER --
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_detall BEFORE INSERT ON detall
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
Declare stock INT;
SET stock = (select existencias from productos where id_fab=NEW.fab AND id_producto = NEW.producto);
IF NEW.cantidad > stock THEN
SET NEW.cantidad = stock;
END IF;
SET NEW.preu = (select precio from productos where id_fab=NEW.fab AND id_producto = NEW.producto);
END;
--
DELIMITER ;
```

I've already checked the fields name's and are ok. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: what error you got? Remove instructions until you dont have the error, then add it back, until you found out who is the guilty statement,    Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: post the error too

Answer (score 0):

Try with `SELECT INTO`

```
SELECT INTO stock
       existencias 
FROM productos
WHERE ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!There's the correct code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_before_insert_detall() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $F_before_insert_detall$
Declare stock INT; 
BEGIN
stock = (select existencias from productos where id_fab=NEW.fab AND id_producto = NEW.producto);
IF NEW.cantidad > stock THEN
NEW.cantidad := stock;
END IF;
NEW.preu := (select precio from productos where id_fab=NEW.fab AND id_producto = NEW.producto);
RETURN NEW;
END;
$F_before_insert_detall$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_detall BEFORE INSERT ON detall FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE F_before_insert_detall();
```

Thank you so much anyway :)